# What's the name of the first piece of music in Shingeki no Kyojin episode 1?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In the 1st episode of SNK / AOT, there's this awesome song at 0:47, when the colossal titan appears. Do you know the name, please? I can't find it anywhere...

Comment: Is it the song in this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XoWJV88_MA)?

Comment: no, it's not in the clip. it's before the opening.

Comment: Magical eren, I'm not sure which one You are searching for, but the one which is played when colossal Titan appears in the first ep is the one unlimited burst refers to. The soundtrack's name goes by XL-TT, if this is not the one you are searching for, take a look at this link to find the one you are searching for: http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/%22Attack_on_Titan%22_Original_Soundtrack

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is referring to when the colossal titan appears in the prologue before the intro.

The song is called **cóunter・attàck-mˈænkάɪnd (Counterattack Mankind)** and is from **Attack on Titan Original Soundtrack**.

The actual part featured in the mentioned scene starts over half way through the track at around **3:25**, which is possibly why it is hard to find.

It is composed by Hiroyuki Sawano.

The track can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PuP7IkpRLU

Comment: It is worth noting that since this is a Sawano soundtrack, the title is typeset as "cóunter・attàck-mˈænkάɪnd" in the album (http://vgmdb.net/album/38626).

Answer (score 0):

The song youre looking for is named Attack ON Titan, not Counterattack - Mankind. 
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oi_TTMjobng